# Diferença entre HttpClientBuilder.create().build(), HttpClients.createDefault() e DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, web-service, apache, http, http-request

Ao criar uma conexão Http usando:

`HttpClientBuilder.create().build(), HttpClients.createDefault()`

ou:

`DefaultHttpClient`.

Qual a diferença?

```
private static CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

private static CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

private static DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

E qual a mais indicada para utilizar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá,

1. `HttpClients` é uma interface para auxiliar você na criação de classes que herdem da classe abstrata `CloseableHttpClient` (Neste caso, ela implementa tanto a interface `HttpClient` quanto `Closeable`);
2. `HttpClientBuilder` é uma classe auxiliar que utiliza do padrão de projetos ***BUILDER*** (Ou ***Factory***, se preferir) para criação de classes que herdem de `CloseableHttpClient`;
3. `DefaultHttpClient` é uma classe que herda de `AbstractHttpClient`, na qual essa herda de `CloseableHttpClient`.

Além disso, o método `build()` e `createDefault()` geram uma classe `DefaultHttpClient`. Resumindo, tudo a mesma coisa só que de formas diferentes de se implementar.

Espero ter ajudado. :-)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Só mais uma duvida você explicou que o build() e createDefault() geram uma classe DefaultHttpClient e quando eu uso a DefaultHttpClient diretamente ele fica como deprecated.

Então para mim não ter esse alerta o mais indicado e eu utilizar um dos outros dois métodos?

Comment: Isso mesmo @DavidSoares!

Comment: Entendi obrigado.